# Server that echos the client number?

Tags: python, tcp, client, echo, server

Trying to make a server that tells the client what number he/she is. For example, once you connect it should say something like "Welcome client #5" or something along those lines. Right now I'm just trying to write it so that it simply reads a line in and echos it back. Im stuck on as far as getting it to show the clients number.

```
import socket
import sys

host = ''
port = 37373
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)

while 1:
    s, address = s.accept()
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data:
        s.send(data)
    s.close()
```

Comment: Just wondering what is the client number you're looking for?

Comment: Lets say im the 4th client to connect, then I would be looking for 4.

Answer (score 0):

that is

```
import socket
import sys


Clinet_number = 0
host = ''
port = 37373
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(10) # number of queued connections 

while 1:
    Client_number += 1
    s, address = s.accept()
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data:
        s.send(str(Client_number))
    s.close()
```